# How to search for a value in any nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

Basically I have to find a matching value in all the fields in my document.

I tried using query string but unfortunately, it only searches in first-level fields. The nested field values are not fetched using query string or may be the way I am using it is wrong.

I tried

```
GET events/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "*",
            "query": "match"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

how will I query such a way that it checks all the fields including the nested fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always have multiple clauses, one for the first level fields, and another for nested fields combined in an OR condition:

```
GET events/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "*",
            "query": "match",
            "lenient": true
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nested_field",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "nested_field.*",
                "query": "match",
                "lenient": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it already it throws an exception.

`GET events/_search
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"default_field":"*","query":"match"}},{"nested":{"path":"log","query":{"query_string":{"default_field":"log.*","query":"match"}}}}]}}}`

This is the exception I got

`{"shard":0,"index":"events","node":"5IC8ImhhQgSf5xUl2OL1qA","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: For input string: \"match\"","index_uuid":"ns4mhSq-Qoy2e72ND6Pd_g","index":"events","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"match\""}}}`

Comment: I've modified the query, please try again